# Get nested data and sharp into DTO with nested DTO

Tags: entity-framework, linq, dto

I'm newbie to EF, Linq and C# in general, I'm stuck with developing following.
I cannot map data into structure like this:

```
Id,
Actions [
  Action1,
  Action2,
  Action3
]
```

I have 2 DTO classes like this:

```
public class TestDTO
{
    public int TestId { get; set; }
    public TestDTO2[] Actions { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class TestDTO2
{
    public int TestActionId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

I've separated calls to DB into file called BusinessLogic, I'm doing it like this:

```
    public IQueryable<TestDTO> GetNested(Filter filter)
    {
        var query =
                    from a in db.Table1.AsQueryable()
                    select new TestDTO
                    {
                        TestId = a.Id,
                        Actions = (
                            from b in db.Table2.AsQueryable()
                            where a.Id == b.TestId 
                            select new TestDTO2
                            {
                                TestActionId = b.TestActionId,
                                StartDate = b.StartDate
                            }
                        ).ToArray()
                    };
        return query;
    }
```

I'm getting following error:

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Project.Core.Models.TestDTO2[] ToArrayTestDTO2' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't perform exactly this query, it is better to make two simple queries and then process their results on client side:

```
var main = db.Table1.Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Title }).ToList();
var mainIds = main.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();
var actions = db.Table2.Where(x => mainIds.Contains(x.TestId)).Select(x => new 
{ 
    x.TestId,
    x.TestActionId, 
    x.StartDate
}).ToList();

var result = main.Select(x => {
    var actions = actions.Where(y => y.TestId == x.Id).Select(y => new TestDTO2
                  {
                      TestActionId = y.TestActionId,
                      StartDate = y.StartDate
                  }).ToArray();
    return new TestDTO 
    { 
        TestId = x.Id, 
        Title = x.Title, 
        Actions = actions.Length == 0 ? null : actions
    };
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks that's works perfectly as I needed. For instance in case if I have no matching of Actions, I anyway have empty array of TestDTO2. Is there possibility to omit it? Also how to populate main with more properties. Thanks.

Comment: If I'm adding new properties here:

var main = db.Table1.Select(x => new {  x.Id, x.Title }).ToList();

Then I'm getting error message on line:

var actions = db.Table2.Where(x => main.Contains(x.TestId))...

main.Contains have conflicts with converting int to anonymous type.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can't use any c# method that can't translate a sql in EF.
actually, you need get a list,then covert it to your DTO

```
 db.Table1
   .Join(db.Table2,
   a => a.Id,
   b => b.TestId,
   (a, b) => new
   {
      a.Id,
      b
   })
   .GroupBy(k => k.Id, v => v).ToList()
   .Select(a=>new TestDTO
       {
         TestId = a.Id,
         Actions = a.Select(b=>
         new TestDTO2
           {
              TestActionId = b.TestActionId,
              StartDate = b.StartDate
           }.ToArray()
         }).ToList()
```

Comment: Hi in the line: TestId = a.Id, I'm getting error, a doesn't expose any of the properties.